# Как убрать произвольные поля на некоторых страницах?

Tags: wordpress, acf

На сайте есть блок "ссылки на соцсети", который присутствует на странице "Контакты", а также на всех страницах в хедере и в футере.
Добавил произвольные поля (в которых ссылки на соцсети) с помощью плагина Advanced custom fields к странице "Контакты".

[image: админка плагина]

В админке на странице "Контакты" появились соответствующие поля.

[image: админка_контакты_1]

[image: админка_контакты_2]

Всё вроде хорошо, но только если я нахожусь на странице "Контакты". На любой другой произвольные поля не выводяться.
Попробовал в админке произвольных полей добавить в "Местоположении" дополнительные правила для отображения полей. Указал всего и много ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... и в итоге поля выводятся, но теперь в админке в Записях, Рубрика, Страницах,  вообщем везде присутствуют мои произвольные поля. А мне они в админке нужны только на странице "Контакты".

Подскажите, так и должно быть или я сделал что-то не так.

Comment: "Всё вроде хорошо, но только если я нахожусь на странице "Контакты". На любой другой произвольные поля не выводяться."  Зачем же нужны были дальнейшие манипуляции если "мне они в админке нужны только на странице "Контакты"."?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что если я в админке добавляю произвольные поля только для страницы "Контакты", то и на сайте (и в хедере и футере) эти поля присутствуют только на странице "Контакты". А на всех остальных страницах сайта (в хедере и футере) их нет.

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка, если я всё правильно понял, состояла в том, что я пытался выводить данные произвольных полей следующими способами:

- `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'название поля', true); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_field('название поля', get_the_ID(), false); ?>`

Т.е. подставлялся ID-шник страницы на которой я в данный момент находился. Поэтому мне и приходилось в админке добавлять необходимые произвольные поля ко всем страницам. 
Решение оказалось очевидным. Просто нужно было получать ID-шник не с помощию `get_the_ID()`, а конкретно указать ID страницы у которой были необходимые мне произвольные поля. В моём случае это была страница "Контакты" с ID-шником "13".

[image: страница Контакты]

И получать данные из произвольных полей со страницы "Контакты" (в моём случае) нужно было так:

- `<?php the_field('название поля', 13); ?>`